Timeout Issue with Keycloak OIDC Authorization Code Flow on Safari macOS
When using the OIDC Authorization Code Flow for a server-side web application, logging in from Safari on macOS results in a timeout. There are no issues when using Chrome or Firefox on Windows.
We are using Keycloak 26.0.7, and the web application uses the keycloak-connect library version 26.0.7 for Node.js. Both Keycloak and the web application are running on AWS EC2 instances, and an ALB (Application Load Balancer) with an ACM SSL certificate is being used.
The steps to reproduce the issue are as follows:
When entering a username and password on the Keycloak realm's login page, a 504 Gateway Timeout occurs upon redirection back to the web application's URL.
I expect the web application's page to open.
Keycloak running on an EC2 VM is deployed using docker-compose. The compose.yml configuration file is as follows:
services:
  keycloak:
    image: keycloak/keycloak:26.0.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      - KC_DB=mariadb
      - KC_DB_URL_HOST=mariadb
      - KC_DB_URL_PORT=3306
      - KC_DB_URL_DATABASE=keycloak
      - KC_DB_USERNAME=keycloak
      - KC_DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=keycloak
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      - KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true
      - KC_PROXY_HEADERS=xforwarded
      - KC_HOSTNAME=https://auth.example.com
    command: start
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "5m"
        max-file: "10"
    depends_on:
      - mariadb

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.5.2
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=keycloak
      - MYSQL_USER=keycloak
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "5m"
        max-file: "10"

volumes:
  mariadb-data:

The Node.js web application is using express and keycloak-connect to protect index.html. Below is the sample code:
import express from "express";
import session from "express-session";
import Keycloak from "keycloak-connect";

const app = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use("/public", express.static("./public"));

const memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();
const keycloak = new Keycloak({ store: memoryStore });
app.use(
    session({
        secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET || "this is default session secret",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        store: memoryStore,
    }),
);
app.use(keycloak.middleware());

app.use(keycloak.protect());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("./index");
});

Keycloak is listening at https://auth.example.com, and the Node.js web application is listening at https://app.example.com.
When accessing https://app.example.com, the web application's Keycloak protect process is triggered, and the user is redirected to the Keycloak login page. While the login page is accessible, after entering the username and password, the Authorization Code Flow execution times out.
